# PL/SQL: ERROR ORA-00984 can anyone save my life?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

hello guys can you help me here

```
CREATE TRIGGER operation
AFTER UPDATE ON COMPTE
for each row
BEGIN
IF :old.solde > :new.solde THEN 
INSERT INTO HISTORY VALUES(NUMEROCOMPTE,DATESOLDE,'Retrait');
end if;
IF :old.solde < :new.solde THEN 
INSERT INTO HISTORY VALUES(NUMEROCOMPTE,DATESOLDE,'Versement');
end if;
end;
/
```

this is what i get

```
3/1       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
3/41      PL/SQL: ORA-00984: Column Not Allowed
6/1       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
6/41      PL/SQL: ORA-00984: Column Not Allowed
Errors  : check compiler log
```

i'm new so i dont know what to do

Comment: *i'm new so i dont know what to do*. You should start by understanding that SQL or code will not end your life, so relax. The next thing is that you can greatly improve the quality of your experiences here by spending some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting. We have no information about what you're trying to do other than what you've posted, and we can't read your mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do as Ken commented.

---

Problem is with `insert` statements (both of them) and values you're trying to insert into the `history` table. You can't insert column names as such - you have to precede their names with `:new` or `:old` pseudorecord identifier, just as you did in `if`.

I don't know which values (old or new) you want to store into the `history` table so it is just my guess, but you should know it and you'll therefore be able to fix
it.

Sample tables:

```
SQL> create table compte (solde number, numerocompte number, datesolde date);

Table created.

SQL> create table history (muberocompte number, datesolde date, description varchar2(20));

Table created.
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> CREATE TRIGGER operation
  2    AFTER UPDATE ON COMPTE
  3    for each row
  4  BEGIN
  5    IF :old.solde > :new.solde THEN
  6       INSERT INTO HISTORY VALUES(:old.NUMEROCOMPTE, :old.DATESOLDE, 'Retrait');
  7    ELSIF :old.solde < :new.solde THEN
  8       INSERT INTO HISTORY VALUES(:new.NUMEROCOMPTE, :new.DATESOLDE, 'Versement');
  9    END IF;
 10  end;
 11  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```